# What does the authorizeRequests in Spring Security do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have been experimenting on having a multiple security config for different api endpoint as of the moment I have this configuration:

```
http
    .antMatcher("/user/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/document/**").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

this configuration is working but I am also confused that when I tried to remove the second `authorizeRequests()` (See below). The configuration is also working.

```
http
    .antMatcher("/user/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/document/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

What does this method do? And do I have to call it every time?

Comment: You could repeat every method, because of *method chaining*. But you don't need it. For better readablity you shouldn't repeat any method. Also in some cases it is possible that the second call overwrites the first call.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the documentation:

> Note that the matchers are considered in order.

In your configuration, `/user/**` gets the precedence over `/user/document/**`. So, in both of cases, the second `antMatcher(...)` is never applied.
Answering your second question (Do I need to call it every time?) - the answer is **NO**. Here is a sample configuration (again from the documentation):

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin();
```

Comment: *In your configuration, /user/** gets the precedence over /user/document/** That's wrong. I reformatted the question, to make it more clear.